# Trying to get a document with Streambuilder from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get Documents from Firestore with a StreamBuilder by their Id. It seems to be a simple mismatch in variables, but I dont understand how to fix it, please help

lib/view/widgets/task_stream_builder.dart:72:18: Error: The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.

- 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'DocumentSnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.15.3/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.15.3/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  .snapshots(),
  ^
  Restarted application in 343ms.

  ```
     return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
           .collection('members')
           .doc(memberId)
           .snapshots(),
       builder: (context, memberSnapshot) {
         if (!memberSnapshot.hasData) {
           return Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
           );
         }

         var memberDoc = memberSnapshot.data!.docs.first;

         Map<String, dynamic> memberData =
             memberDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is reading a single document, so the result is a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` (not a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`).

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>(
  ...
```